# Создать exe файл из строки с кодом python

Tags: python-3.x

Вот в чем вопрос, я пишу loader (builder), нужно что-бы после строки print("Готово, сейчас сделаем билд!") он создал exe файл в котором будет прописан код который я укажу в builder, как так сделать?
Вот код:

```
import getpass
import urllib.request
import os
import time
import zipfile
import getpass
import urllib.request
import os
import time
import zipfile
print("Выберите действие: \n1 - Инструкция\n2 - Лоадер\n3 - Джойнер")
n = int(input("Действие:  "))

if n==1:
 print("Инструкция по эксплуатации: \n1.Залить файл (лучше всего на dropmefiles.net)\n2.Перейти на страницу загрузки.\n3.ПКМ по кнопке загрузки (та что начинает загрузку) и копировать ссылку.\n4.Вставить ее в MalwareAgent.\n5.Наслаждаться результатом (:")

elif n==2:
 print("Выбрано действие: Лоадер")
 basa=input("Введите ссылку для скачивания: ")
 folder=input("Предполагаемое имя папки: ")
 print("Готово! Сейчас сделаем билд...")

elif n==3:
 print("Выбрано действие: Джойнер")

else:
 print("I can't doing this action")
```

Comment: А минуса за то что у нас принято задавать конкретные вопросы.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо, так моя задумка может быть реализована?

Comment: Хорошо, моя ошибка. Вы сможете мне помочь? Сейчас переформулирую задачу

Comment: Примите ответ если он вам помог (галочка около ответа)

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonicam это stackoverflow на русском, Поэтому комментарии нужно оставлять на русском языке

Answer (score 0):

Установите pyinstaller:

```
pip3 install pyinstaller
```

```
...
import os
...
var_with_code = input("Code: ")
os.system("echo "+var_with_code+" > code.py")
os.system("pyinstaller code.py")
...
```

Comment: Примите ответ если он вам помог (галочка около ответа)

Comment: в строку var_with_code = input("Code: ") Вставлять сам код?

Comment: Да, сам код (на питоне)

Comment: Перенос строк в \n?

Comment: Да \n. (for new line)